# ¿Por qué no me pone todo lo que tiene el archivo dentro de un jtext de java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Al querer mostrar todo el contenido del archivo solo me muestra lo ultimo en el jtext y si lo imprimo en consola me pone todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void bt_SubirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("C files", "c"));
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String url = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(url);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            String linea;
            
            
           
            **while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
                
                
                textoC.setText(linea+"\n");
                
            }**
            
            
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Excepcion leyendo fichero " + url + ": " + e);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Holaa, el problema es que estas usando setText(), esto remplaza todo el texto por uno nuevo, a medida que lea una linea remplaza todo el texto por esa linea nueva, la solucion es usar:

```
area.append(linea+"\n");
```

Esto agrega texto a lo que ya esta escrito

Comment: Gracias bro!! si era eso

Comment: BRAYAN, puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta haciendo click en el check all lado de la puntuación, revisa el [tour].